# [Java]Incorrect output using jar file via console

Tags: java, sorting, intellij-idea, jar, insertion-sort

List of russian names from input txt file

- Александр
- Роман
- Михаил

This code sorts these names correctly in IntelliJ Idea during debugging.
When I create a jar file and run it from the windows console `java -jar E:\\sort-it.jar`, then in the output file the first name is Роман, although it should be Александр, as in debugging.

The incorrect order from jar launch is

- Роман
- Александр
- Михаил

The correct order is

- Александр
- Михаил
- Роман

What could be the problem?

```
package programs;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

  public static String inputFileName = "E:/in.txt";
  public static String outputFileName = "E:/out.txt";

  public static List<String> FetchFileData(String fileName) throws IOException {
    List<String> tempArray = new ArrayList();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        tempArray.add(line);
    }
    reader.close();
    return tempArray;
  }

  public static List<String> SortWords(List<String> inputArray) {
    String temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); i++){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < inputArray.size(); j++){
            if (inputArray.get(i).compareTo(inputArray.get(j)) > 0){
                temp = inputArray.get(i);
                inputArray.set(i, inputArray.get(j));
                inputArray.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
  }

  public static void WriteToFile(List<String> inputArray, String fileName) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); i++) {
        writer.write(inputArray.get(i));
        writer.newLine();
    }
    writer.close();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> unsortedArray;
    List<String> sortedArray;                
    unsortedArray = FetchFileData(inputFileName);
    sortedArray = SortWords(unsortedArray);
    WriteToFile(sortedArray, outputFileName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use a Collator as shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7633680/4636715
This way you add the Locale to the code explicitly rather than relying on the İntelliJ's one.

Comment: But if I need write sort algorythm manually, how I can improve my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small problem is that FileReader uses the default platform encoding.
In the IDE & Windows that could be another that in the console.
Better do:

```
public static List<String> FetchFileData(String fileName) throws IOException {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("Cp1251");
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), charset);
}
```

Specifying the charset of your files ensures that the application is portable to other computers (with the same file). `Files` provides support for writing too.

Ensure that every line trimmed of spaces and maybe the Unicode BOM character, `\uFEFF`:

```
String line = lines.get(i);
line = line.trim().replace("\uFEFF", "");
```

That there are better solutions that `compareTo` has already been said.

No sneeky Latin lookalike letters were inserted instead of Cyrillic.

The code looks fine too.

So check the charset; something else I do not see, as unlikely as it is.

Comment: Changing charset in FetchFileData method help me. Big thanks!